# How to show/hide item within a list item MVVM kendo

Tags: javascript, html, templates, kendo-ui

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="my-template">
    <ul >
        <li>
        <div onclick="showToggle()"> Show/Hide Form</div>
        <div id="myform"> My Form Stuff</div>
        </li>
    <ul>
</script>
```

So in the above I want to click on the div or button and what ever and toggle the other part of the list item.

```
            <ul data-role="listview" id="myList"
                data-bind="source: listOfStuff"
                data-template="my-template"></ul>
```

now I can't really assign IDs to this. I just want to toggle it with some function like below.  Maybe this is more of a javascript question.  I guess I could also add another variable to my list of objects in my mvvm and then set that to visible true on a click, but I'd rather not add on the to the view model.

```
function showToggle(){
if ( $('#myform') visible) do
   $('#myform').hide();
else 
  $('#myform').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery On to attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. Set class selector for your div and register click handler for that class.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="my-template">
<ul >
    <li>
    <div class="show-hide"> Show/Hide Form</div>
        <div>My Form Stuff</div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log( e ); // e is div 
});
```

Comment: I want that div below it to open and close.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to make it clickable